How to Properly Integrate Google and Apple SSO with AWS Cognito / Amplify?
I'm currently working on a React Native Expo project and trying to integrate Google and Apple Single Sign-On (SSO) using AWS Cognito and Amplify. I've followed the documentation but seem to be missing something as the SSO buttons do not work as expected. Here's what I've done so far:
Configured AWS Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool:
    Set up Google as an identity provider in the Cognito console.
    Provided the necessary client IDs and secret keys for both providers.

Installed AWS Amplify:
    Added aws-amplify and @aws-amplify/ui-react-native to my project.
    Configured Amplify with my Cognito details in the aws-exports.js file.

Implemented SSO in React Native:
    Created a login screen with buttons for Google and Apple login.
    Used the useAuthenticator hook from @aws-amplify/ui-react-native to handle federated sign-in.

Updated App.js:
    Configured Amplify in App.js using Authenticator and Amplify.configure.

Used AWS Amplify Documentation:
    Followed the AWS Amplify documentation to set up the necessary configurations and install required packages.

Here are the additional packages I've added based on the documentation:
{
  "@aws-amplify/react-native": "^1.1.1",
  "@aws-amplify/rtn-web-browser": "^1.0.30",
  "@aws-amplify/ui-react-native": "^2.2.2",
  "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
  "aws-amplify": "^6.3.6",
  "aws-amplify-react-native": "^7.0.8",
  "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.4"
}

Here is the relevant part of my App.js:
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import amplifyconfig from '../amplifyconfiguration.json';

Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator.Provider>
      <YourMainComponent />
    </Authenticator.Provider>
  );
}

And here is the relevant part of my TabOneScreen component:
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';
import { setToken } from '@/store/slices/authSlice';
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from '@env';

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { toFederatedSignIn, signOut } = useAuthenticator();

  const login = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Login button clicked'); // Debug log
      await toFederatedSignIn({ provider: 'google' });

      const token = AUTH_TOKEN;
      console.log('Token received:', token); // Debug log
      dispatch(setToken(token));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error logging in', error);
    }
  }, [dispatch, toFederatedSignIn]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={login}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Login with Google</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {/* Similar button for Apple SSO */}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#4285F4',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});

Issues:
Login Button Not Working: Clicking the login button does not trigger the SSO process.
No Errors or Debug Logs: There are no error messages or logs in the console, making it hard to diagnose the problem.

What I've Checked:
AWS Amplify is configured correctly in aws-exports.js.
Google credentials are correctly set up in the Cognito console.
useAuthenticator hook is imported and used correctly.
Followed AWS Amplify documentation and added necessary packages.

Questions:
Is there a specific configuration needed in the Cognito console for Google SSO?
Are there additional steps required to make toFederatedSignIn work in a React Native project?
How can I debug the issue effectively to understand why the SSO buttons are not working?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated along with help related to adding Apple SSO.

Check official documentation, there are detailed explanations regarding all SSO authentication : https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react-native/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/
